# Jquery move Div element Animate

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm newbie to Jquery and I'm working on a new animation . What I want is move a Div id to specific position where is an anchor point, without using a percentage or pixels .

I attached an Image to understand the scenario

[image]

Comment: You should try out some tutorials related to jquery API like `animate()`.

Comment: "where is an anchor point" - there are many anchor points… to which one you want to move the div… when do you want to move the div..? and btw did you try something?

Comment: Which div you want to move to those anchor points? Is it that car???

Comment: To move DIV i'm using appendTo. Here is en example : $('#myDiv').appendTo($('#targetAnchor'));. 
http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

Comment: When someone click on a year i need to move that car into that specific year . for an example if somebody click on "2003" the car should move to 2003 .

Comment: What is without using percentage or pixel??

Comment: I've used the Jquery animate method and what i was doing is moving the element with "margin-left:50px;" & "margin-left:20%;" and likewise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that purpose, I prefer using [$.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), like below:

```
$( ".anchor" ).click(function() {
  //difference between your "car" element with your div destination
  var posDif = $(this).offset().left - $(".block").offset().left; 
  $( ".block" ).animate({ "left": "+="+posDif }, "slow" );
});
```

Check out this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U6faD/2/

Please understand the logic, so you can change some part of that code and reach your goal.